# CometD in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, dojo, cometd

How to run the demo (Client: JavaScript API, Dojo  Server: Java ) in cometd-2.3.1 package on tomcat server? Since I am new to this topic, please provide detailed steps

Answer (score 1):

The demo is built with Jetty server. I'd suggest first to run it as is, and study the documentation and the mailing list posts related to the demo.
After these steps you should be able to create your own app on your preferred web server. But I could not find a straightforward way of adapting the demo to a generic web server.